# Trying to update table with primary key of three other tables

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am still pretty new at doing sql queries I am trying to update a table with the primary key of three other tables. I am not getting any errors but it is clearly not working because my table is not updating... Can someone tell me what I have done wrong??

Update table is called "set_color"

```
$results_array = mysql_query("
    SELECT * school_art
    JOIN  baseimage 
    ON school_art.series_code = baseimage.basefolder 
    WHERE baseimage.image_type = 'B' 
    UPDATE set_colors SET 
    set_colors.school_art_id = school_art.id,
    set_colors.baseimage_id = baseimage.id,
    set_colors.baseimage_layer = baseimage.layer
    ;");
    return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but according to the [update syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) we have to shuffle it around a bit:

```
UPDATE set_colors
JOIN  school_art
JOIN  baseimage 
ON school_art.series_code = baseimage.basefolder 
set_colors.school_art_id = school_art.id,
set_colors.baseimage_id = baseimage.id,
set_colors.baseimage_layer = baseimage.layer
WHERE baseimage.image_type = 'B'
```

- Always first `UPDATE`
- Then the table references, including any `JOIN`'s you want to do
- Then `SET`, followed by the columns to set (in a JOINed query, you could also set columns in other tables, not only the first).
- Then the `WHERE` clause.

However: do not run this yet: this will update the *WHOLE* table. Based on what columns in set_colors do you want to select the records that should be updated?

Comment: Thank you, yes I would like to update certain records. I was creating a class so would something like this work:

Comment: `public static function update_ set_colors($value) {UPDATE set_colors
JOIN  school_art
JOIN  baseimage 
ON school_art.{$value} = baseimage.basefolder 
set_colors.school_art_id = school_art.id,
set_colors.baseimage_id = baseimage.id,
set_colors.baseimage_layer = baseimage.layer
WHERE baseimage.image_type = 'B'`

Comment: For the query, we need to know based on what columns in set_colors we can select the rows.